# Android Notification - How to create a system based on model properties

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I've been trying to implement Notifications in my app without effectively succeeding. The following are my observations:

**Requirements:**

1. After scheduling a Notification it has to be repeated on a monthly basis.
2. The notification will be inflated with some model object data, so the object needs to be passed to the notification builder.

**How I tackled the problem so far:**

I created a `NotificationScheduler` object that basically creates a `PendingIntent` for the notification to be fired.

```
object NotificationScheduler {
    fun scheduleNotification(context: Context, model: Model, cal: Calendar) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11)
        val notificationIntent = Intent(context, NotificationPublisher::class.java)
        notificationIntent.putExtra("model", Utils.parcelToBytes(model))

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    }
}
```

Then I have a `NotificationPublisher` class that should show the notification and set the next one by calling `NotificationScheduler` again.

```
class NotificationPublisher: BroadcastReceiver() {
    var model: Model? = null

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val modelBytes = intent?.getByteArrayExtra("model")

        if (modelBytes != null) {
            model = Utils.bytesToParcel(modelBytes, Model.CREATOR)
        }

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationBuilder(context!!, model!!)
        val notification = notificationBuilder.buildNotification()

        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

        //schedules the next notification

NotificationScheduler.scheduleNotification(context, model!!, Calendar.getInstance())
        }
    }
```

Where the `NotificationBuilder` class just takes the `context` and the `model` and builds the notification

```
class NotificationBuilder(val context: Context, val model: Model) {

    fun buildNotification(): Notification {
        generateNotificationChannel(context)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sub)
                .setContentTitle(model.title)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

        return builder.build()
    }

    private fun generateNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "Test"
            val description = "description"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

            val channel = NotificationChannel("ID", name, importance)
            channel.description = description

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
```

**My problem with this approach:**

It works if I purposely display the notification as soon as it is created, but I get a NullPointerException whenever the user, for example, reboots his device or kills the process. While debugging I found out that the data I store in the `notificationIntent` in `NotificationScheduler`, once the device is rebooted, isn't available anymore in the `onReceive()` of the `NotificationPublisher` and therefore will generate a NPE.

I think I am doing something conceptually wrong with this approach, and I'd like you to help me figure out how to achieve the above mentioned requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.., I am not going in details of your programming problems and will not help you to find the error.. But i have read your question keenly neatly and got the problem and its solution too..!! It is a bit theoretical.. But as i can see your programming skills are good .. so you just needs the direction and concept clearance.

### Here we go :

> It works if I purposely display the notification as soon as it is created, but I get a NullPointerException whenever the user, for example, `reboots` his device or `kills` the process.

This is the main cause of the problem. Whenever system reboots or whenever system kills the app.

> What causing it...?

Whenever system is rebooted "All the alarms set by `AlarmManager` are no more preserved and needs to be re-scheduled again by the application"

> What is work around then...?

Maintain a table of scheduled alarms. As soon as system fires `ON_BOOT_COMPLETE` re-schedule all again.

> Most of the devices in market not triggering my `ON_BOOT_COMPLETE` receiver..!!

Yes most of the devices now a days are keeping only major companies services like `google`, `facebook`, `whatsapp`, `twitter`, `instagram` and rest all others are discarded at boot time.

> Why mobile manufacturers does this?

As it is a business and it also improves performance and speed of the overall device. And if they do not allow said companies services on reboot .., then no one will take such phones..!!

> Any solution for this..?

Use firebase job dispatcher. Let Google play services handle your service.

I hope it helps you and correct me if i am wrong or if need any further clarification over the issue. Thanks

### EDIT 2

I would suggest create a job schedular job via your mainactivity `context` and let it handle google play services which will start executing job on `every reboot`. That job should call a foreground service with a proper notification. And via that foreground service again call to an `intentservice` which will `re-schedule` all the `alarms` by reading from Sqlite table one by one.

### Edit : 3

Even if you follow these all paradigms suggested here... There is another problem you will notice..

> Google play not starting My foreground service on reboot..!!

Yes..., As Post `Marshmallow` and `modified ROMs` ( including stock android and mobile manufacturers modified OS like OxygenOs, FunTouchOs, ColorOs,.. This list never ends as well) As battery is optimised and no private apps processes can come in memory on reboot..!!

> Now is there any way i can tackle this problem too...?

Yes .. Show user a bold and bright alert :

```
If You want to perform this app normally, 
you must stop optimising battery for this 
app from settings..!!
```

> That what the ways we can tackle these many problems.. Yes i
>   understand it has no well documentation from google and no sample codes too, Still in case if you require any help regarding implementing any `sub-point` I will help you in implementing these all sub-points as well

Thanks you as it helped you